# How to link posts to their respective categories in a CRUD application with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a blog, and I created a table in MySQL to store posts and another table to store categories.

How do I connect each post to its category and fetch all posts based on their categories?

For example, if I view a post titled **PS4**, I want it be under the Gaming category.

Comment: You might want to read up on 'JOINS': http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/

Comment: Show your code, so we can help you out.